# Compare 2 lists using Intersect but in 3rd list should contain match AND property from list 2

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 lists of Objects. I am using Intersect LINQ operator to any match between 2 lists and setting it as a variable. In this newly formed list, I am only able to get the matched value.

I've looked into SelectMany, but don't think it's the right solution for this.

```
var CommonList = iMIScustomersList.Select(s1 => s1.Company).ToList().Intersect(zendeskCompaniesList.Select(s2 => s2.name).ToList()).ToList();
```

I want to get the matched value and from the matched value in list 2, I want to get the id property as well. For example s2.id in zendeskCompaniesList. Currently using Intersect I am only getting the matched value and no other properties from that match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is Join, instead of Intersect.

```
var CommonList = iMIScustomersList.Join(zendeskCompaniesList,
                      cust=>cust.Company,
                      comp=>comp.Name,
                      (cust,comp)=> new {Customer=cust,Company=comp}).ToList();
```

For example,

```
var iMIScustomersList = Enumerable.Range(1,10)
                                   .Select(x=> new Customer{Name = $"Name{x}", Company=$"Company{x}"});
var zendeskCompaniesList = Enumerable.Range(5,10)
                                   .Select(x=> new Company{Name=$"Company{x}", Location = $"Location{x}"});
var CommonList = iMIScustomersList.Join(zendeskCompaniesList,
                      cust=>cust.Company,
                      comp=>comp.Name,
                      (cust,comp)=> new {Customer=cust,Company=comp}).ToList();
```

Sample Output

[image]